# HTML5 Regex Pattern: Allow alphanumeric and up to 3 spaces, underscores, and hyphens

Tags: regex, html

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9 _][a-zA-Z0-9]{2,24}$
```

That's what I have right now.

I want to require an alphanumeric first; allow for alphanumerics, underscores, hyphens, periods, and spaces; require that it end with an alphanumeric.  But I only want to allow as many as 3 of those special characters.

I'm primarily confused about how to limit the number of the special characters.

Comment: give some example valid and invalid data

Comment: If you're allowing as many as 3 special characters, do they have to be in a row, or 3 total? So is something like A-B-A valid?

Comment: 3 total. They can be consecutive or spread out. They just can't start or end the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use this regex:

```
/^(?!(?:[a-z\d]*[_. -]){4})[a-z\d][\w. -]{0,22}[a-z\d]$/i
```

The look-ahead `(?!(?:[a-z\d]*[_. -]){4})` is to check that there are less than 4 appearances of invalid characters. If there are 4 or more, then the pattern inside the negative look-ahead would match, and make the look-ahead fail.

Since the string must start and end with alphanumeric, and the length is at least 2, it is possible to specify `[a-z\d]` as start and end of the string. The rest of the character in between can contain any of `[a-zA-Z0-9_. -]` repeated 0 to 22 times, since 2 characters are already use for the starting ending alphanumeric.

Comment: Hmm, I've never seen a look-ahead inside a negative look-ahead. That's pretty slick. What's the difference between `?:` and `?=` ?

Comment: So close. As far as I can tell the only problem with your solution is that HTML5's regex checker is case-sensitive and does not respond to the `/i` flag.  So it's necessary to drop it and manually specify uppercase letters as valid.  This means that the pattern should be `^(?!(?:[a-zA-Z\d]*[_. -]){4})[a-zA-Z\d][\w. -]{2,22}[a-zA-Z\d]$`  Thanks, nhahtdh.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard: That's not look-ahead inside negative look-ahead. It's just simply a negative look-ahead `(?!pattern)`, with a non-capturing group `(?:pattern)` repeating 4 times.

Comment: For some reason I wasn't familiar with that. Thanks for teaching me something.

Answer (score 1):

**Okay, this should be the last edit:** Didn't think about the total character limit. Added look-ahead (assuming your flavor of regex supports it).

There may be a better way than this, but it's not coming to me (maybe using lookaheads). Here's what I can think of:

```
^(?=^.{2,24}$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+([a-zA-Z0-9]*[_\-. ]){0,3}[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

It's not too pretty but it should work.

Comment: Can be simplified to `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(([a-zA-Z0-9]*[_\-. ]){0,3}[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$`, and the length check can be done separately.

Comment: True, if needed (or preferred for style or just to keep the regex from getting to messy).

Answer (score 0):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[ _.-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]*[ _.-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]*[ _.-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

There's probably a better way to do this, but I think you could just have the invalid characters be optional, appearing at most three times, with the other valid characters showing up 0 or more times in between them